# RVM fails to install Ruby 1.9.3 on Lion: libxml2.2.dylib

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, rvm, clang, ruby-1.9.3

I keep on reading tons of these threads at stack overflow and other sites, different reasons why everyone is failing to install either 1.9.2 or 1.9.3, but none of them helped me for the past week. So my last resource is, well, make my own thread!

When installing, I get the following:

```
Pablos-MacBook-Pro:~ Pablo$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /Users/Pablo/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #compiling 
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/Pablo/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

And */ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log* ends with the following:

```
installing default syslog libraries
linking shared-object tcltklib.bundle
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64) for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/tcltklib.bundle] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/tk/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

What can be going on? I'll answer in advance some questions since I've read so many articles by now.

- I'm running Mac OS X Lion
- I'm running (what I think it is) the latest Xcode version: 4.3.3
- I tried doing this: **CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3**
- I tried using clang: **rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang**, and it fails with the same error, plus it throws a: **clang: error: unsupported option '--with-libyaml'**
- I can install 1.8.x versions, but fail with 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 with the same error.

So, we got a nice puzzle here. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe libxml was build as 32bit and can not be used for building 64bit ruby, you can verify it with:

```
file /usr/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
```

if it's the case you need to reinstall it with support for 64bit

Comment: Got that right: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib: Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386 — So what do I have to reinstall, this library? If so, how do I install the 64 bit version? Thanks!

Comment: Your reply made me search in the right direction. Thanks! This post totally did the job: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2010/07/08/installing-ruby-1-9-2-with-rvm-on-snow-leopard/